# How to use an external dependency using javax.validation instead of jakarta.validation in Spring 6?

Tags: spring, bean-validation, jakarta-migration

Due to the upgrade of the Spring version of a project from 5.3 to 6.0, the javax.validations were replaced by jakarta.validations successfully, but our project also imports a external dependency, via pom, in which the interfaces use javax.validation and we can not modify them.

We have implemented on our code the endpoint defined in those interfaces but since that upgrade the validation does not work because both the endpoint and the used model is implemented using javax.

Any idea?

Comment: update the external library version, maybe it has a newer version that uses jakarta instead of javax?